# Подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое параметр в CSS?

Tags: css3, html5

Реально нигде не могу найти определение. Вижу в контексте "Если был передан только один параметр методу scale(), то он применит этот коэффициент и к высоте и к ширине". Смысл я то понимаю, но ловлю себя на мысли, а что же все-таки такое параметр? Почему бы просто эти числа в скобках не называть значением?

Answer (score 2):

Параметр функции не называют значением по той же причине, по которой не называют значением переменную. Как и переменная, параметр представляет множество значений, а конкретное значение принимает в момент вызова функции, когда параметру сопоставляется аргумент функции, который и дает конкретное значение - либо явно заданное, либо как результат вычисления выражения. Заметьте, что параметр (как и переменная) не становится значением, а принимает значение. Разница существенная.

Если говорит именно о функциях, то сходство параметров с переменными неслучайно - параметр и есть локальная переменная функции. Отличие только в том, что параметр функции при вызове инициализируются аргументом.

Кстати, ваше определение не совсем верно, потому что оно говорит о параметре, имея в виду аргумент. Хотя терминология может немного разниться - встречаются, например, названия "формальный параметр" (то есть именно параметр), и "фактический параметр" (то есть аргумент). Аргумент тоже нельзя назвать значением, потому что он может быть переменной, выражением, вызовом другой функции, и т.д.

Если посмотреть шире, чем контекст функции, то параметризовать можно и другие вещи. Говоря о программировании, параметр может представлять собой тип (в шаблонах) или даже кусок кода (в макросах). Можно сказать, что параметр позволяет пользователю объекта адаптировать его каким-то образом..

Answer (score 1):

Параметр - Величина, характеризующая какое-н. свойство устройства, явления, системы и т. п.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/340300)

Comment: Является ответом на вопрос. И отвечает на него в полной мере.

Comment: Формально отвечает, а по сути является пустопорожней болтовней. Не надо вытаскивать цитаты из википедии или откуда там вы это определение выдернули. Ответьте своими словами, но по существу, чтобы ТС было понятно.

Comment: Понятнее чем в википедии некуда. Параметр он и в css параметр и в Африке параметр.